# Свой сервис использующий OAuth 2.0 на Java

Tags: java, oauth2

Здравствуйте.

Что нужно для реализации своего сервиса на **Java** использующего **OAuth 2.0** для раздачи токенов?

Comment: Принести в жертву двенадцать девственниц на крыше многоэтажного дома в полночь.

Comment: ***Принести в жертву двенадцать девственниц на крыше многоэтажного дома в полночь. – @faoxis***  

есть разница какого они будут возраста? )

Comment: Да, больше 66. У нас все по взрослому.

Comment: И еще возьмите их детей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё уже реализовано за Вас, остается только воспользоваться:

1) фреймворк [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html)

2) Реализация OAuth от Apache [Apache Oltu](http://oltu.apache.org)

Выбирайте на своё усмотрение.

Comment: А вариант не используя Spring Security?